# Centroid and Outlier calculation

Tags: outliers

I have this question, but to be honest i am stuck

1.Considering a set of 60 users, an a maximum number of objects that a user can own equal to 4000, which approach would you choose to calculate the centroid in terms of owned objects ,and their distance from the centroid to identify the outliers?

The outlier can be defined as an user that owns a set of objects very different from the centroid.

Do you have any suggestion on how to approach?

Thanks!